# How to move all zero values to the end of the array with LoDash/Underscore?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

Assume I have an array of objects:

```
    var a = [
      {label: 'one', value: 0},
      {label: 'two', value: 5},
      {label: 'three', value: 9},
      {label: 'four', value: 4},
      {label: 'five', value: 2},
      {label: 'six', value: 0}
    ]
```

Now I need to put all items in ascending order which is easily done with `_.sortBy`, but then I want to put all zero values from the start of the array to the end, so I have values row looking like `2, 4, 5, 9, 0, 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom iterator and the [Infinity property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) for the value representing the 0s and thus push them to the end :

```
var s = _.sortBy(a, function(o) {
    return o.value || Infinity ;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/LwYpq/

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks:) As stable as the base sort on equal values, I'd say.

Comment: @nikoshr As per the documentation, `_.sortBy` is stable. So you are right :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with underscore library, like this

```
var _ = require("underscore");

var result = _.partition(a, function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.value !== 0;
});

console.log(_.flatten([_.sortBy(result[0], "value"), result[1]]));
```